# What Is the best way to connect or disconnect a Laptop from power?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery-life, connector, battery

While connecting/disconnecting laptop's power connector seems to be convenient, I am concerned about person's and laptop's safety of doing it this way.

Somewhere I read that connecting/disconnecting should be done using the laptop's adapter power plug and not the power connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely disconnect a laptop from the power source from either end. Power adapters are safe piece of hardware that must respect international regulations and won't spike when disconnected, or otherwise damage your computer.

However, a laptop power cord can be a safety hazard to adults and children alike, and even your computer. It's a lengthy cord that can be tripped upon by someone. Disconnecting from the wall, but leaving it attached to the laptop may drag your laptop with it, if someone trips on the cord. Conversely, leaving it around attacked to a wall outlet, may become a problem to people walking close to it.

Ideally, it should be disconnected on both ends, and stashed away. But being that not convenient for whatever reason, make sure it's at least disconnected from the laptop end and shoved against the wall, or otherwise out of other people harm's way.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the correct way would be, switch off the socket switch, plug in the adapter to the socket and also into the laptop and then switch it on from the socket and then power up the laptop. When the battery is fully charged, then you should unplug the adapter from the laptop. When disconnecting from the laptop, you ought to shutdown the computer first, switch off from the socket and then unplug the adapter.

Comment: Well i want to use battery as backup and surge protector together in order to be free from hassle of buying UPS, doing checkups and replacing UPS battery. I want to keep battery 40%-60% charged.